# PHPmailer unable to connect

Tags: php, phpmailer

I've been trying to get PHPmailer to work but I stumble constantly on the same error. I made a gmail account and normally all settings should be right.

I get the following error: Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.

This is the code I'm currently using:

```
<?php 

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;


require 'PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
    $mail->Username   = 'mymail.com';
    $mail->Password   = 'mypassword';
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';encryption
    $mail->Port       = 465;

    $mail->setFrom('mymail', 'Dev4');
    $mail->addAddress('anothermail');
    $mail->addReplyTo('no-reply@gmail.com', 'Information');

    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
```

Comment: It's most likely that your hosting provider is blocking outbound SMTP, so it's nothing to do with your settings, which are otherwise correct. Read [the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting) for further advice.

Comment: Set SMTP debug to `SMTP::DEBUG_LOWLEVEL` (refer from document) just to see debug messages but I think @Synchro was right, it maybe blocked from your hosting.

Answer (score -1):

You just need to fix the following two lines...

```php
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->Port       = 587;
```

and add

```php
    $mail->Mailer = 'smtp';
```

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't work either. I get the following error:
Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. Connection failed. stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed

Comment: Did you enable email sending in gmail itself?
Here's a helpful article: https://www.jotform.com/help/392-how-to-use-your-gmail-account-as-your-email-sender-via-smtp/

Comment: No, the OP's settings are fine, and you shouldn't set `Mailer` directly.